# Objective-C – Where/when to run a check for ignored UILocalNotifications

Tags: objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have a little programming challenge. In my app I'm using repeating `UILocalNotification`s. I have written a method to deal with ignored notifications, in the method I check if a notification has been ignored then I log this to a Core Data entity called `EntityA`. So say for instance a repeating notification is set to repeat every day. If the user ignores that notification for 10 days, we would have 10 missed notifications, which would be 10 `EntityA`s.

Where would it be appropriate to put this method when I check for ignored notifications? I'm thinking in:

`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` - If the application wasn't running when notification was fired

`applicationWillEnterForeground:` - If application was in the background when notification was fired and the user ignored the notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to put the checking methods in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and `applicationDidBecomeActive:`

That way my app will always have accurate data when launched.